# I'm having a problem understanding the realloc function in C

Tags: c, realloc

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int* cut(int* x, int n);

int main() {
    int *x= NULL,n;
    x = malloc(sizeof(int));

      
    printf("Amount of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", x);

    x = realloc(x, (*x+1) * sizeof(int));
    assert(x != NULL);// allocate memory and ensure that this was successful
    for (int i = 1; i <= *x; i++) {
        printf("%d Element: ", i);
        scanf("%d", x+i);
    }
    printf("pper barrier: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    x = cut(x,n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= *x; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(x+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(x);
}

int* cut(int *x, int n) {
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= *x; i++) {
        if(*(x+i) < n) {
            *(x+a) = *(x+i);
            a++;
        }
    }
    *x = a-1;
    x = realloc(x, (a+1) * sizeof(int));
    return x;
}
```

The code works fine however I do not unterstand the line `x = realloc(x, (*x+1) * sizeof(int));` Furthermore I don't get why the first `x` has `no *` but the second `(*x+1)` has one. Does this mean a pointer of the pointer?

I think it  just  means that the array malloc that was made is getting bigger by one value However  I'm not sure and a still a bit confused  what that actually means, could someone please help me out and clarify my missunderstanding?

Comment: Where did you get the code from?

Comment: Friend and book

Comment: This code is an attempt at being "fancy" by storing the array length in the first element. But it makes the whole code look very unidiomatic and confusing

Comment: You allocate one `int`, you read a value into that telling you how many additional elements you will have and then you allocate `(*x+1) * sizeof(int)` more.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = realloc(x, (*x+1) * sizeof(int));
```

Let's start with this part:

```
x = realloc(x, ...
```

The code is calling `realloc` and passing as the first parameter whatever `x` points to and storing the result in `x`. That means that the block currently pointed to by `x` will be resized and the result stored in `x`. So `x` will point to a resized version of whatever `x` pointed to before.

The `(x + 1) * sizeof(int)` is the size of the block. Let's start with the right side, `* sizeof(int)`. That means enough space to store some number of `int`s. How many `int`s? `*x + 1` of them.

So this means to change `x` to point to a resized version of the block `x` already pointed to, resizing the block to hold one more integer than the value of the integer `x` points to.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not unterstand the line `x = realloc(x, (*x+1) * sizeof(int));`

`x` is an `int*`. `*x` dereferences `x` (so that you get the value entered by the user in the previous `scanf("%d", x);`). So, `(*x + 1)` means, "the value entered by the user plus one". Take that and multiply it with the size of an `int`. The `x` argument to `realloc` is the pointer with a prior allocation that you want to increase the allocated memory for. The returned pointer (that may be the same or a new value as the prior `x`) is then assigned to `x`.

> Furthermore I don't get why the first `x` has no `*` but the second (*x+1) has one. Does this mean a pointer of the pointer?

`x = ...` means "assign a value to `x`". `realloc` returns a `void*` which can be implicitly converted to any pointer type, like an `int*`, and `x` is an `int*`.

In `(*x + 1)` the `*` is used to dereference `x`, that is, fetch the value of the `int` that `x` is pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> scanf("%d", x);
> ```

This sets the integer at the address `x` to the value that the user typed. For example, if the user types `3`, this line does the equivalent of `*x = 3;`.

> ```
> x = realloc(x, (*x+1) * sizeof(int));
> ```

`*x` is dereferencing `x`, not making a pointer to `x` (that would be `&x`). So it's the value that the user typed. So this line makes `x` point to an array of N+1 elements, where N is the value that the user typed. (Assuming the memory allocation succeeds.)

Later, in `cut`,

> ```
> *x = a-1;
> x = realloc(x, (a+1) * sizeof(int));
> ```

these two lines again maintain the invariant that the first element of the array is the number of elements that follow.